# TextView (in RelativeLayout along with ImageView) getting hid after loading image in ImageView using Picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-relativelayout

I have this `RecyclerView.Adapter` set up. In it's `onBindViewHolder()` I'm loading image through URL using `Picasso`.

Here's `PhotoRecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class PhotoRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Photo> photos;
    private Context mContext;

    public PhotoRecyclerAdapter() {
        photos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Photo photo = photos.get(position);

        holder.imageBy.setText(photo.getUser().getFirstName());

        Picasso.get().load(photo.getUrls().getSmall()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView imageBy;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageBy = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBy);
            mContext = view.getContext();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's `item-photo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item_photo"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageBy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here image is getting set in the `ImageView` but nothing is getting shown in the `TextView` but when I comment out `Picasso.get().load(photo.getUrls().getSmall()).into(holder.imageView);` the text is getting shown.

What's wrong here?

Comment: On First Bind Please Print your TextView data and Url using Log .And then see it which what data are coming though API in two cases .

Comment: @RAHUL both are printing out. As I said that text is getting shown when I'm commenting out the line which loads image into `ImageView` which means it is there but getting hid by the Image.

Comment: Then you can adjust your .xml correctly.